# Angular ui.router provide state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular/rails app with 2 pages that needs to serve 2 templates:

The states are currently displayed with `<ui-view></ui-view>` on 2 different pages:

1. http://localhost:3000/employees
2. http://localhost:3000/employees/help_desk

The problem is that for #2 to display the correct state, the user needs to go to the http://localhost:3000/employees/help_desk#/help_desk URL. Instead, I need the user to be able to go to http://localhost:3000/employees/help_desk and the router to serve the #/help_desk template.

How would I achieve this?

ui.router code so far:

```
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  //home state
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
          postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
            var a = posts.getttAll();
            return a;
          }]
        }
    })

    //help desk state
    .state('help_desk', {
      url: '/help_desk',
      templateUrl: 'help_desk/_help_desk.html',
      controller: 'HelpDeskCtrl',
      resolve: {
      postPromise: ['help_desk', function(help_desk){
        var hd = help_desk.getttAll();
        return hd;
      }]
    }
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to serve the same page from server regardless of what URL the user accesses.
2. You need to enable HTML mode by calling $location.html5Mode(true) in your config phase.

More info on html5Mode: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: I have 2 entirely different pages, and 2 different templates. I am just trying to get the two to match. employees with home template and employees/help_desk with help_desk template. So, I am confused on how suggestion 1 would work?

Comment: The first option is needed, so that when the user directly enters the url it correct page is loaded. What you want from your server is to load the same HTML + JS (including your Angular app) regardless of what URL you are using. The second option tells angular (ui-router) to parse the URL and identify the state from that without using the hash. To sum up: option one is for clients directly entering the url, option two is for navigating within the site. You would need to do both.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever router are you using, you can change route by url part after `#` sign only. Changing any part before affect application to reload.

Please take a look at this [example](https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/helloworld)

Please do not look at `templateUrl` - this is loaded separately.

Comment: The thing is, I actually need a page reload at this point. All I need is if someone goes to /employees to display the home template. If someone goes to the /employees/help_desk to display the help_desk template. Is there not a way to do this by differentiating the <ui-view> call on the 2 separate pages or something like that?

Comment: If you are using separate page that means you loading different index.html  and you can use different script. So you can modify router configuration to use another template for root route. Doing like that is very awkward and weird...